# Call external URL to setup and teardown in Testcafe

Tags: testing, installation, automated-tests, testcafe, teardown

I'm using Testcafe with an application that has a database driven backend (no API, but MVC).

I would like to Setup and Teardown settings in the database prior to running the tests. This can be down by calling an URL on my application (e.g. https://myapp.local/setup?foo=bar or https://myapp.local/teardown?foo=bar)

I would like to call these URLS from within Testcafe, prior to running the test. I have looked at the module `testcafe-once-hook`(https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-once-hook) and the accompanying examples (https://github.com/AlexKamaev/testcafe-once-hook-example)

```
import { oncePerFixture } from 'testcafe-once-hook';

const setupDb = oncePerFixture(async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('https://myapp.local/setup?foo=bar');
});


fixture `Setup db`
    .before(() => {
        setupDb;
    })

    test('Test1', async t => {
        /* Test 1 Code */
    });
```

but the URL in setupDb is never called as I can see from my Apache logfiles.

I also looked at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1345#issuecomment-338796731, but here also the URL is never called as I can see from my Apache logfiles.

```
fixture `Setup db`
    .before(async ctx => {
        ctx.hasSetup = false;
        // Server-side actions
    })
    .beforeEach( async t => {
        if (!t.fixtureCtx.hasSetup) {
            await t.navigateTo('https://myapp.local/setup?foo=bar');
            t.fixtureCtx.hasSetup = true;
        }
        else {
            return t;
        }
    })
```

How can I achieve that https://myapp.local/setup?foo=bar is called beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I'm running
`testcafe@6.14.11`
and
`testcafe-once-hook@0.0.4`
and this has solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

I examined your code and found some mistakes that can lead to incorrect behavior.
I modified your code, please check it:

```
import { oncePerFixture } from 'testcafe-once-hook';

const setupDb = oncePerFixture(async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('https://myapp.local/setup?foo=bar');
});


fixture `Setup db`
    .beforeEach(setupDb);
```

or

```
fixture `Setup db`
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await setupDb(t);
     });
```

Comment: Hi @alex-kamaev,
Thanks for the reply. I have implemented above code (both example 1 and example 2), but still the page is not called.

In VSCode I'm getting a warning on the import line:

`Could not find a declaration file for module 'testcafe-once-hook'. '/path/to/node_modules/testcafe-once-hook/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/testcafe-once-hook` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'testcafe-once-hook';`ts(7016)`

I'm not sure if it's relevant. Sorry for the late reply, had a short holiday

Comment: I tried the `testcafe-once-hook` module with my example, and it looks like something changed in TestCafe, so the `oncePerFixture` function does not work as expected.

Please create a separate issue in the TestCafe github repository using the following link: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md).

As for the warning, it is caused by your TypeScript settings, so it cannot be the cause of the described issue.

Comment: Thanks. See https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6453

Comment: Do you know I which version of Testcafe it should work? So I can at least continu with building tests, awaiting the fix?

Comment: It looks like the module works correctly in v1.14.2.

Comment: any idea why Testcafe waits a couple of minutes after calling the Setup url

Comment: > I would like to Setup and Teardown settings in the database prior to running the tests.
Do you want to do it before each fixture or before the whole test run?

Comment: @mlosev both are options for me. Before/after each fixture I can setup/teardown for that specific fixture, before the whole test run I can set up everything at once. I have no preference.

Comment: We are working on the functionality for setting a global before/after hooks for fixtures and tests, however, at this moment it's difficult to say precisely when it will be released. Please follow our announcements.

Comment: Where can I subscribe to the announcements @alex-kamaev?

Comment: For detailed information about major releases, you can track the following page: [https://testcafe.io/release-notes](https://testcafe.io/release-notes)
To track patches and minor releases, you can visit the [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/releases](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/releases) page. You can also visit the [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/745](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/745) issue to track our progress on this functionality.